# How do I power my Arduino Micro directly?

Tags: battery, arduino-micro

I just need some confirmation, before I break something. So far I have been powering my project from USB, no I would like to power it from a battery. The official spec claims I should use a voltage anywhere from 7-12V, so I got myself a 9V block battery and would connect the positive lead to the VIN pin and the negative lead to the ground pin right next to it, based on this schematic: https://40.media.tumblr.com/cdadca4e95808b376de52a88a5468367/tumblr_mi61oww6cu1s5t695o1_1280.png
Do I need a resistor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-micro-schematic.pdf) schematic, VIN goes to the on arduino-micro's 5 and 3 volt regulators.  So you should not need a resistor.

The 5 volt regulator needs a bit more than 5 volts at it's input to do a good job.  That is why the specification calls for 7 to 12 volts.